# Show that $\nu^c _L = (\nu ^c)_R $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, neutrinos, chirality, majorana-fermions

Considering Majorana neutrinos, how can I show that $\nu^c _L = (\nu ^c)_R $?

I don't know how to answer this question.

And what is the difference between $\nu ^c _R $ and $(\nu ^c)_R $? I know it corresponds to the chirality of the neutrino but I don't understand the difference the brackets make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Majorana basis, Majorana spinors satisfy equation
$$ \psi^c = i\psi^* $$
Also in the Majorana basis $\gamma_5$ is purely imaginary $$ (\gamma_5)^* = -\gamma_5$$
and we have
$$ (P_L)^* = \left(\frac{1-\gamma_5}{2}\right)^* = \frac{1+\gamma_5}{2} = P_R$$
We have then
$$(\nu_L)^c = (P_L \nu)^c = i(P_L\nu)^* = iP_R\nu^* = P_R(\nu^c) = (\nu^c)_R$$

The difference between $(\nu^c)_R$ and $(\nu_R)^c$ is about whether you first perform projection on the specific chirality or charge conjugation; these two operations do not commute, so there is a difference.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes perfect sense now, and thank you so much for the definition in the end.